# How we can know what views are existed in particular table

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle there is table named customers. If we want to know what views depend on the customer table how can we find that out?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_objects_related_to_table_scripts.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

You could query the [sys.all_dependancies](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_DEPENDENCIES.html#GUID-F9EA7DFB-5471-4B07-BDEF-FDE5DF57D1F4) object.
This will output the referencing object which is the name of the view using the table specified

```
SELECT referenced_owner || '.' || referenced_name as table_name,
       referenced_type as type,
       owner || '.' || name as referencing_object,
       type as referencing_type
  FROM sys.all_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_type = 'VIEW'
   AND referenced_name = 'customers' -- put your table/view name here
```